# Can this drain valve be repacked?

Tags: plumbing, valve, boiler, hydronic

[image]

Can this valve be packed?  I've got two of them and they both leak from the stem if they are even cracked open.

On most valves the stem packing nut screws down over threads on the valve, compressing the packing.  The nut like thing on this stem is flanged and appears to be compressed all the way.

If it was threaded in, I would just replace it, or be ready to replace it.  However it's soldered in.  I am not the world's best pipe solderer. This will require draining  the two sections of pipe between the manifolds and the boiler.  I want to be sure I have a solid way to removing air from the system before I mess with this in mid winter.

For what it's worth, now that I have had it open for a week with a pressure valve on it, the drip around the stem has slowed.  May be a case of packing that dried out.

Comment: If you're able to turn the water off, it looks like the "hat" that the stem goes through is removable.  You might be able to disassemble and repack/recondition.

Comment: If not, you can always replace the whole valve...